# Securing SQL Server Database Access Exclusively for Custom C# Software: Seeking Alternative Solutions Beyond Users, Roles, and Encryption

Tags: c#, sql-server, security

I am faced with the challenge of restricting access to a SQL Server database in a manner that only my software can retrieve and utilize data. To clarify further, I aim to create a scenario where even the most privileged user of the database is unable to establish a connection to the SQL Server, even in the event of having access to both the server and the database.

Clearly, relying on SQL Server users and roles is insufficient to address my requirement. Active Directory in Azure also falls short, as anyone with server access and authentication credentials can establish a connection to the database. Data encryption is not a viable solution due to the complexity of numerous stored procedures that cannot be modified, and encryption adversely affects software performance. Additionally, data masking is not suitable for my needs since my software relies on unmasked data. Thus, I am seeking an alternative solution to restrict database access in a way that ensures only my software can retrieve data.
So, any suggestions? My software is written in c#.

Comment: What if you have an issue and your software breaks? You'll have no means at all to recover your database? Seems a bit risky.

Comment: @DaleK Software always have backup which is capable of working with database.

Comment: Encryption is the only way because other methods can always be broken by reading log file or just the page data or starting a dac connection. But I'm pretty sure you don't need these requirements. Just go with the standard user/role/whatever setup

Comment: @siggemannen I need to disrupt the connections from other software currently accessing my database.

Comment: Why? No sane software on earth needs this

Comment: You can look into login triggers that kill connections for processes to coming from your app, but they are probably possible to circumvent. As soon as someone can access your machine, you can't have full security because they can just step through your program code and emulate whatever your program does to gain access

Comment: @siggemannen Yes, that's correct. Someone with access to the database can potentially manipulate triggers. Using triggers for large databases can be highly risky, as it has the potential to cause significant disruptions. Thank you very much. Now I'm considering attempting to terminate other connection processes in my own code.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to kill other connections? What are you afraid of?

Comment: This sounds like madness and a recipe for disaster. Just encrypt your sensitive data in the application.

Comment: @siggemannen I aim for my software to be the exclusive means of accessing the data, ensuring that even if the most robust SQL Server credentials are compromised, the access is restricted to my application and not replaceable by other third-party applications.

Comment: @Stu Testing it in a controlled environment won't be harmful.

Comment: Ok, you probably just have to accept the fact that it will be possible to access your data some other way. But you can always offload some data to another place like the cloud to which only you have access